# is mathematica the right tool to find analytical expressions (using symbolic variables) and to derive constraints based on that?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I do not use mathematica so far, but was wondering if it can be used for my problem:

Given a function of two variables
$f(x,y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n N_i(x,y) E_i$

where $E_a$ are real, positive numbers that are to be determined via optimization, and $N_i$ are scalar functions (piecewise polynomials) that I also can not specify further because they depend on $n$, which is a model parameter.

I want to compute the determinant of the $2\times2$ Hessian of $f(x,y)$ to eventually find constraints on the $E_a$ so as the determinant is greater than zero. In other words, I want to derive linear or non-linear combinations (e.g $c_1E_1 + \dots + c_nE_n > 0$) that make sure $f(x,y)$ is convex on its domain. The $c_i$, depend, of course, on the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$.
This should work without telling mathematica how the $N_i$ look like and what $n$ is. So partial derivatives should appear as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial N_i}{\partial x}E_i$, similarly as one would compute it on a paper.

Can I do that with mathematica?
In matlab, for instance, this does not work smoothly because I can not define $n$ as a symbolic variable.

Update:
Maybe it is worth to note that I want to compute the constraints only at $n$ points in the {x,y} space.

**Edit:**

I implemented the suggestion in  the comments:
[image]

However, this system can not be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
This makes sense to me; one would have to determine the ranges for x and y in which the determinant of a combination of $n$ functions $N_i$ are positive.

It works if I specify $n$. E.g., $n=2$, the output is
[image]

As you can see, the output is basically intangible -- as expected without knowing properties about the $N_i$.

**However, my objective is to have the determinant positive only at given points in the {x,y} space.
Is there a way to pass the information to consider all partial derivatives as constant in the calls to "Reduce or Resolve"?**

Comment: This may indicate a direction to go: `expr = Inactivate[Sum][n[i][{x, y}] e[i], {i, 1, number}]` and `hess = D[expr, {{x, y}, 2}]` then `Det[hess]`, then you would use Reduce or Resolve to continue, but I can't see yet how one could continue  without specifying number

Comment: You might also look at the docs for LinearOptimization and associated functions to see if there is something there which may help.

Comment: @CraigCarter I tried your suggestion, however, Reduce can not solve the inequality (see edited question). I also asked a more precise question. Do you have any remedy?

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like you have not defined the function det (Mathemamtica is case sensitive and determinant is Det)

Comment: @bills Yes, I corrected this, but the issue is the same. Can you help?

Comment: I guess I would try with a fixed n first, to make sure all the details are correct. If it works for specific n, then even if it fails for generic n, maybe you can see the pattern as n increases.

Comment: @bills Reduce works if I specify n (see edited question). However, the output is hard to read even for $n=2$. But I think it would be quite readable if mathematica knew that all expressions involing $N_i$ are constant in the call to Reduce (because I evaluate them at given points). Do you see a way to incorporate this information?